# EmbersJS: Tutorial on building an application from scratch using REST API

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm quite new to EmberJS framework to build Web Applications. I'm currently struggling to understand the right way (using Models, Controllers, View and Routes) to build a full-fledged web application using a Java (Spring, Hibernate) based REST API.

My current task is to create a simple registration page using EmberJS and pass on the information to a back end server using the REST API.

Can anyone guide me on this from scratch or show me few links that would help me learn?

Answer (score 0):

This video was helpful when I was learning how to build an ember app with a rails rest api. Yehuda is on the rails core team and one of the primary creators of ember.js so I think he's a pretty good source of information.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BpQj9_qEUAc

Comment: Anything without rails?